# Get JSONObject by some attribute of object from JsonArray

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have resevationTickets json array,i need to get specific reservation ticket object from above mentioned json array and using ticket id.how do that?

json array like this:

```
reservation_tickets[
{object 1},{object 2},{object 3}
]
```

**object has tx_id;

i need to find right ticket using tx_id

Comment: post your JsonArray

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
org.json.JSONObject
org.json.JSONArray

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_array);
int size = jsonArray.length();

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
    if(json.getString("tx_id") == tx_id){
      //here we go...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks amit,but my jsonArray has large number of index,so ineed efficiency way to do that

Comment: finally i changed my json format as reservation_tickets[
"id1":{object 1},"id2":{object 2},"id3":{object 3}
] and changed my code like this ticketJson = (JSONObject) reservationJsonObj.get(tx_id);its worked.